# increment in for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, increment

I don't know why but I can't increment value in for loop normally.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
var number= 0
number++
console.log(number);
}
```

That's the simple example,and I get 5 times number 1 in console,insted of 0,1,2,3,4.
How I can make that work?

Comment: Move the number declaration outside the for loop

Comment: Thanks,it works,but why I get in console(1,2,3,4,5),insted of (0,1,2,3,4)

Comment: Then shift `number++` below the `console.log`

Comment: Because you increment before you `console.log()`. If you want the value of `number` at the start of the loop, `log` first.

Comment: You are aware you can write `console.log(i);`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're declaring the variable inside the loop, so it happens every time the loop runs.  Simply move the declaration outside...

```
var number = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    number++;
    console.log(number);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It prints 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 because you reset `number`in every iteration.

change your code to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

or

```
var number = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(number);
    number++;
}
```

(Answer to additional question in comments) You get 1,2,3,4,5 because you increment `number` before you print it.

Answer (score 1):

You keep resetting the value of `number` to 0. Try setting it before the loop:

```
var number= 0
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(number);
    number++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
<script>
var number = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    number++;
    console.log(number);
    alert(number)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you're declaring the number variable inside the for loop, so it gets reinitialized to 0 with each iteration. To fix this, you should declare the number variable outside the loop, before it starts. Here's the corrected code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  number++;
  console.log(number);
```

With this change, the number variable will retain its value across iterations, and you'll see the expected output of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to iterate in range from 0 to 5, you can use "**i**" variable.

```
for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

but if you need use for some reason another variable as you name it "**number**", in javascript you can write too as belowe

```
let number = 0;
for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
   console.log(number++);
}
```

or

```
for (let i=0, number=0; i<5; i++) {
   console.log(number++);
}
```